# Display Images with replacing description

Tags: jquery, replace, image-gallery

I have a folder with some images like:

1.jpg
2.jpg

With this sample-code i display the images:

```js
var temp = "<div class='gallery' style='width:{width}px;'><img src='Sources/img/{index}.jpg' width='100%'></a></div>";

var limitItem = 49,html="",w=1;
for (var i = 1; i < limitItem; ++i) {
  html += temp.replace(/\{width\}/g, w * 160).replace("{index}", i);
}
document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML=html;
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
</div>
```

I wish to use the picture-name for the description. My idea is, to format the picture like this:

- 1_mountain
- 2_dogs
- 3_trees

How can i build a replacing string for replacing the alt-tag of a image with the description text? Is it at even possible?

```js
html += temp.replace(/\{width\}/g, w*160).replace("{index}",i).replace("     {description}",xxxxxxx);
```

```html
<img alt='{description}' src='Sources/img/{index}.jpg' width='100%'>
```

Comment: Please when making snippets, make [mcve] and not just paste code. Also hit TIDY before saving

Comment: you can replace the alt text, same way you replace "{index}"

Comment: But with what? The Description can be every letter from a-Z. I tried with regex but it didnt work:

replace("{description}",^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$);